# iOS UICollectionView switch cell NIB dynamically

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am updating my iOS app from table views to collection views to support a "gridded" option.
I have two cell types. One that is more suitable to a "tableView" type look, and takes up the full width of the screen. The other is a cell that is more suitable for grids.

I can't use the same cell type for both because the tableView type cell has a lot more horizontal information than the grid cell.

I have a button press event that will cycle between my cell types, updating the layout and changing the cell reuse identifier appropriately. The problem is, any cells that were already in view do not change to the new cell type. If I scroll for a bit, the new cell types start coming in.

I imagine that this has something to do with the dequeue function for collectionView taking an indexPath. I can explicitly reload those cells to get them to use the new type, but this causes an unwanted animation, not to mention feels like a hack.

How can I switch cell types dynamically?

Linked is a video demonstrating the issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CGfb.jpg

As you can see, after I change the cells they remain using the old NIB (with all the extra information). But if I scroll down the new NIB will be used.

Comment: call layoutifneeded after the cell change

Comment: reload cells after the change

Comment: I tried layoutifneeded but that didn't work. I am reloading the cells after the change, but that causes a kind of double animation that I'd like to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solution for this: -

1. Use two collection view for each type of cell, hide and show respective collection view on click of button.
2. Remove the collection view from super view on click of button, add again and reload

Comment: I think right now the double animation is preferable to a crossfade animation as it’s way more contextual.